# Attached file in email loses content

Tags: c#, email, attachment

When I attach a file to an email it loses its content on the way.

First I get the file from a form (to a HttpPostedFile):

```
File file = Request.Files["file"];
```

Then I add it as an attachment to the email.

```
if (file != null && file.ContentLength != 0)
{
       formData.File.InputStream.Position = 0;

       var attachedFile = new Attachment(file.InputStream,                                                                           
       file.FileName,                                                
       MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);

       mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachedFile);
}
```

But on the way its contentlength becomes 0. What goes wrong? Do I have to do something with the file before I can attach it? The file appears with its filename in the email, but has no content.

Comment: When you attach "attachedFile" to "mailMessage" the contentlength is okay?

Comment: Problem solved. The stream is used multiple times and has to be reset with `stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`

Comment: This means that the (first) stream (attempt) filled the first attachment correctly but then not anymore?